# Fast i/o function implementation

Tags: c++, performance

I was searching net about fast i/o in c++ for various contest and i found one piece of fast input function . But i am just a beginner in c++ and couldn't implement it to a simple programme to input using that function . So if someone can give an example code like to input a variable using that function , it would really be a help to me . Here's is the function i found :-

```
inline void fastRead(int *a)
{
 register char c=0;
 while (c<33) c=getchar_unlocked();
 *a=0;
 while (c>33)
 {
     *a=*a*10+c-'0';
     c=getchar_unlocked();
 }
}
```

Comment: Really? You're a beginner in C++ and couldn't implement a simple program with it but your concern is optimizing the I/O that your program will, eventually, perform after you learn how to write it? Words fail me.

Comment: Well @NikB. , the very first program of spoj is 'enormous input' which requires i/o optimiztion !

Comment: If that's true (and that's something you shouldn't decide until you have actual profiling data from an implementation or years of experience behind you) then I would suggest that you aren't the person for the job assigned. A new programmer cannot be expected to produce performance-optimized code.

Comment: Firstly: any non working code can be optimized to equivalently non working code of a single line. Or less. Secondly: I/O is better to be optimized by reading large blocks instead of single characters.

Comment: @NikB. , its not a matter that its a job , please apply logic , i am a beginner doesnt mean i am a dumb and neither it means that i cant learn fast i/o inputs okay , and if you dont know the answer , please stop being rude atleast . If you know what spoj is , i think you could understand situation better . Thanks anyways

Comment: That function is not a good way to solve your SPOJ problem, but if you want to see how it works - either compile in debug mode and trace through it watching what values the variables take, or add some `std::cout << "c " << c << '\n';` and `std::cout << "*a " << *a << '/n';` lines to show you what it's doing as it reads input. (A better approach is to loop reading characters until you find a '4' or end-of-file, if it's a 4 then read another and see if it's a '2'... I won't spell it all out, but by thinking through the logic at this level you can solve this very very easily.)

Comment: @user1795954 I'm sorry for being "rude"... *rolls eyes*

Comment: @user1795954 you could include a link to the SPOJ question in your stackoverflow question for context....

Comment: "I/O is better to be optimized by reading large blocks instead of single characters" - C is famous for being good at efficiently handling input on a character by character basis, due to good implicit buffering and typically high standards of optimised machine code output.  This was a big issue once-upon-a-time, for writing filters, compilers etc., with the ability to "unget" a character being a significant supporting feature.  C++ maintains C's performance levels here, at least when using the C libraries.  Yes, memory mapping will be faster, but doesn't work on all types of inputs on all OSes.

Comment: @TonyD , my problem was not on that particular question but was on broader topic which would be applicable to almost all contest type problems , so i didnt post the link , anyways here it is http://www.spoj.pl/problems/INOUTEST/

Comment: @TonyD: dd ibs=1 obs=1 file >/dev/null 2.6MB/s vs dd ibs=4096 obs=4096 < file >/dev/null 1.8 GB/s. (Didn't bother to write variable sized block read/write with c)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: and what do you think that means?  If you don't look at the dd source code or trace its system calls, it can't be interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

Do not worry about the speed of your I/O until the speed of your I/O is a problem your program is having. Doing pre-mature optimizations, especially if you do not understand why you are performing a optimization, will likely either cause your program to run *slower* or the amount of time it took to find the optimization will be longer than the total amount of time saved the optimization does over the lifetime of your program due to the fact that what you *thought* you needed to optimize was not what was causing the program to be slow.

Stick with easy to read and maintainable code and go back and do things like optimized I/O **once you have profiled your completed application and you find I/O to be the real bottleneck**

Comment: Well its a problem 'enormous input' for that i really need optimiztion in input ! @Scott Chamberlain

Comment: @user1795954 What profileing you have done that shows that a bottle neck in I/O is your problem, and what is your base line so you know how much improvement you got by changing your code.